# Shared external Angular Library with single-spa

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa

Is there a way to use an angular library as an alternative to single-spa utility module, imported with systemjs in the root application? I want to create a service within this shared library, that can be used by the angular micro-frontend apps as an injectable, preferably as a singleton to share state using rxjs between the micro-frontends.